# Get random 5 star review

Tags: magento-1.9, ratings

What is the most efficient way to get a single, random, 5 star review (from any/all products).

I'm trying to display a single random review on our homepage.  Here's what I'm working with currently but it has several issues.

```
$review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
$collection = $review->getProductCollection();
$collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->getSelect()
            ->limit(5)
            ->order('rand()');
$review->appendSummary($collection);

foreach($collection as $product) {
$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary();
$starRating = $ratingSummary['rating_summary'];

if($starRating == 100) {
    echo "<h1>". $product->getDetail() ."</h1>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
;

$reviews->getSelect()
    ->joinInner(array('rs' => 'review_entity_summary'), 'rs.review_id = main_table.entity_id')
    ->where('rs.rating_summary = 100')
    ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('rand()'))
;

$randomReview = $reviews->getFirstItem();
```

`LIMIT` is not needed here as you are displaying only one record.

Be aware that `RAND()` is not the best idea if you have a lot of records.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There seems to be an issue with joinInner:: Warning: Missing argument 2 for Zend_Db_Select::joinInner(), called in /home/vagrant/app/design/frontend/sm-fcstore/yogavibes/template/randomtestimonial/random_testimonial.phtml on line 46 and defined  in /home/vagrant/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 350

Comment: @AndrewBoehm there was mistake in code, looks ok now

Comment: That seems to have resolved the issue in the system.log however the code is still failing and causing the entire content block not to display.  The issue is resolved if I remove ->joinInner and ->where.  Thanks again for your time

Comment: Any ideas on whats causing the join to fail? @rafal-kos

Comment: I really want to accept this answer as it seems like the proper method however something is not working with joinInner.  It fails without error so I'm not sure what is wrong.  Without it the code returns a random review (just not the 5 star review I'm looking for).

Comment: what kind of error you have in logs? did you try to replace `getResourceCollection()` by `getCollection()`?

Comment: Just tried using getCollection() instead but still no luck.  Ahhh...I"ve been looking System.log....it shows nothing of significance.  But I finally checked exception.log: Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rs.review_id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rafal-Kos suggestion.  Needed to update tables and columns:

```
    $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
;

$reviews->getSelect()
    ->joinInner(array('rs' => 'rating_option_vote'), 'rs.review_id = main_table.review_id')
    ->where('rs.percent = 100')
    ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('rand()'))
;

$randomReview = $reviews->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: why  not just accept the answer provided by RafalKos if that helped you solve the problem.

Comment: It didn't feel right accepting an answer with code that didn't work....but I've switched my acceptance since it was his insight that helped.